# Need to append json response

Tags: javascript, jquery

my response looks something like this:

```
[{
    "letter": "A",
    "data": [{
            "cuisine_id": "1",
            "cuisine_name": "American"
        },
        {
            "cuisine_id": "2",
            "cuisine_name": "Arabic"
        },
        {
            "cuisine_id": "3",
            "cuisine_name": "Asian"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "letter": "B",
    "data": [{
            "cuisine_id": "4",
            "cuisine_name": "Bakery"
        },
        {
            "cuisine_id": "7",
            "cuisine_name": "Burgers"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "letter": "N",
    "data": [{
        "images": "1.png",
        "cuisine_id": "14",
        "cuisine_name": "New Cuisine"
    }]
}]
```

My HTML code looks like :

```
  <ul class="filter-list">
     <li>
   <label class="capital-head">A</label>
   <ul class="clearfix dish-type">
      <li class="inp-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" value="" name="american" id="american">
         <label for="american">Arabic</label>
      </li>
      <li class="inp-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" value="" name="american" id="american"/>
         <label for="american">American</label>
      </li>
      <li class="inp-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" value="" name="asian" id="asian"/>
         <label for="asian">Asian</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I Need to make this static HTML code to dynamic.
I am very new to jquery and javascript.

Image looks like this :
[image: Need to replace the static content and replace with response]

Here is my script that I am getting the response :
on call of this script below I am getting my response from controller class

```
   function getCuisines()
    {
       $.ajax({
              url: "<%=dashboardURL%>getCusines",
              type: "GET", 
              success: function(response)
                          {
                            alert(response); }
              }); 
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far to accomplish that?

Comment: what do you want to append your html to? is there a parent node?

Comment: I just want to replace the static content of HTML code with response

Comment: What is your equivalent html element from json key, like cuisine_id where to replace value of this key to html ?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710798/automatically-generate-html-from-json) help?

Comment: by the way, the reason they're downvoting you is that your question doesn't show your code. please edit it and include what you have attempted to do, even if it doesn't work. nobody is going to judge you

Comment: at label,  need to replace with cuisine_name, at value, need to replace with cuisine_id and this(<label class="capital-head">A</label>) need to replace with letter

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: even id's can be replaced with cuisine_name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON to HTML Table in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216482/json-to-html-table-in-ajax)

Comment: @Manju  did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You need to use `$.each()` to iterate over records.

2.`id` needs to be unique per element that's why I am leaving `id` in my answer

3.Check-box needs to have a corresponding value which I have added to my answer.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
data = [{"letter":"A","data":[{"cuisine_id":"1","cuisine_name":"American"}, 
 {"cuisine_id":"2","cuisine_name":"Arabic"}, 
 {"cuisine_id":"3","cuisine_name":"Asian"}]},{"letter":"B","data": 
 [{"cuisine_id":"4","cuisine_name":"Bakery"}, 
 {"cuisine_id":"7","cuisine_name":"Burgers"}]},{"letter":"N","data": 
 [{"images":"1.png","cuisine_id":"14","cuisine_name":"New Cuisine"}]}];

var html = '';
$.each(data,function(key,value){
 html +='<li><label class="capital-head">'+data[key]['letter']+'</label><ul class="clearfix dish-type">';
 $.each(value.data,function(k,v){
  html +='<li class="inp-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="'+v.cuisine_id+'" name="'+v.cuisine_name+'"><label for="'+v.cuisine_name+'">'+v.cuisine_name+'</label></li>';
 });
  html +="</ul></li>";
});

$('#mydiv').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

***Note:-***

If you are using `ajax` to get the `json` data as `a response` from `PHP` then use `dataType:'json',` in your `ajax` code so that it will parse the data automatically.

Otherwise before using `$.each()` you have to do `data = $.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: @Manju  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Try following. I created string and then append it.

```js
x=[{"letter":"A","data":[{"cuisine_id":"1","cuisine_name":"American"}, 
 {"cuisine_id":"2","cuisine_name":"Arabic"}, 
 {"cuisine_id":"3","cuisine_name":"Asian"}]},{"letter":"B","data": 
 [{"cuisine_id":"4","cuisine_name":"Bakery"}, 
 {"cuisine_id":"7","cuisine_name":"Burgers"}]},{"letter":"N","data": 
 [{"images":"1.png","cuisine_id":"14","cuisine_name":"New Cuisine"}]}];
 
str="";
x.forEach(function(e){
   str+='<li><label class="capital-head">'+e.letter+'</label><ul class="clearfix dish-type">';
   e.data.forEach(function(e1){
        str+='<li class="inp-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="american" id="american"><label for="american">'+e1.cuisine_name+'</label></li>'
   });
   str+='</ul></li>';
});
$("#hi").append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="hi"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below,

```js
var d = [
 {"letter":"A",
 "data":[
  {"cuisine_id":"1","cuisine_name":"American"}, 
  {"cuisine_id":"2","cuisine_name":"Arabic"}, 
  {"cuisine_id":"3","cuisine_name":"Asian"}
  ]
 },
 {"letter":"B",
 "data": [
  {"cuisine_id":"4","cuisine_name":"Bakery"}, 
  {"cuisine_id":"7","cuisine_name":"Burgers"}
  ]
},
 {"letter":"N",
 "data":  [
 {"images":"1.png","cuisine_id":"14","cuisine_name":"New Cuisine"}
 ]
 }
];

function generateHTML(){
 
 
 for(var i =0;i<d.length;i++){
  var li =  $("<li>");
  var dts = d[i];
  var label = $("<label>").attr("class","capital-head").html(dts['letter']);
  $(li).append(label);
  var ul = $("<ul>").attr("class","clearfix dish-type");
  $(li).append(ul);
  for(var j =0; j<dts['data'].length;j++){
   var dt =  dts['data'][j];
   var ulLi = $("<li>").attr('class','inp-checkbox');
   $(ulLi).append($("<input>").attr("type","checkbox").attr("name",dt['cuisine_name']).attr("id",dt['cuisine_name']));
   $(ulLi).append($("<label>").attr("for",dt['cuisine_name']).html(dt['cuisine_name']));
   $(ul).append(ulLi); 
  }
  $("#data").append(li); 
 }
 
}
```

```css
li{
 list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="generateHTML" onclick="generateHTML();" value="generateHTML"/>
<div id="data"></div>
```